# Probability dot product of two binary vectors is equal to $1\bmod 2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $u, v$ be two random vectors with $i$-th element being 1 with probability $p$. What is the probability that $u \cdot v \equiv 1 \pmod 2$?

I could think of enumerating all odd-length subsets, setting values of both vectors to in these subsets $1$ and fixing all other pairs to either $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$.

That is, number of vectors (with binary entries) having dot product equal to $l = 2k + 1$ is $$\binom n l 2^{n-l}$$

and the probability of two vectors taking such 'configuration' is $$p^{2l}p^{n-l}(1-p)^{n-l}$$

Because we can fix $l$ pairs to $(1, 1)$ with probability $p^{2l}$ and assume that the rest of pairs are $(1, 0)$ without taking into account pairs $(0, 1)$ because number of vectors is multiplied by $2^{n-l}$.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably, vectors of fixed dimension $n.$

Comment: The other pairs are one of $(0,1), (1,0)$ or $(0,0).$ And the $(0,0)$ case is not an equal case, so it is going to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be that probability. 
Clearly, $P(0)=0$.
Beyond that, we have the recursion
$$P(n+1)=p^2(1-P(n))+(1-p^2)P(n) =p^2+(1-2p^2)P(n).$$
Thus
$$ 2P(n+1)-1=2p^2-1+2(1-2p^2)P(n)=(1-2p^2)(2P(n)-1)$$
or
$$ 2P(n)-1 = (1-2p^2)^n(2P(0)-1)=-(1-2p^2)^n$$
and finally
$$ P(n)=\frac{1-(1-2p^2)^n}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $q_j$ be the probability that the dot product is $j,$ for any $j=0,\dots,n.$

Let $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} q_jx^j.$ This can be rewritten as $p(x)=((1-p^2)+p^2x)^n,$ since $(1-p^2)+p^2 x$ represents the generating function of the dot product of each bit.

You can use this to compute the $q_{2k+1}=\binom{n}{2k+1}p^{4k+2}(1-p^2)^{n-2k-1}$, but there is a trick that makes computing the sums easier. We can compute:

$$q_1+q_3+\cdots+\cdots =\frac{p(1)-p(-1)}{2}=\frac{1-(1-2p^2)^n}{2}.$$

---

More generally, given a random bit-vector of length $n$ such that each bit is independent and bit $i$ has probability $r_i$ of being $1$, you get that the probability of an odd number of bits is:

$$\frac{1-(1-2r_1)(1-2r_2)\cdots(1-2r_n)}{2}$$

The above case is $r_i=p^2$ for all $i.$